# In SPSS, should I calculate the mean score or the total sum score?

Tags: spss, mean, normalization, sum

Are there any differences between mean scores and total sum scores? I know how to calculate both, I just don't know if there is one of them that is preferable?

Also, the scores will be used for t-test, one-way ANOVA, Pearson's correlation and multiple regression.

Comment: There is a statistical question here pivoting on the difference between mean scores and total sum scores, but only SPSS users can be completely clear on what that means precisely, unless you spell out the definitions for the rest of us. If you're asking which makes more sense for your analysis, I think you would need to tell us much more about your data and your problem.

Answer (score 5):

Given that mean, $\bar{x}$, is:

$\bar{x} = \frac{\Sigma{(x_i)}}{k}$

$k\bar{x} = \Sigma{(x_i)}$

The difference between mean and sum of scores a factor that is equal to the number of items being added $k$. So, the mean differences, as well as intercept and slope would appear to be different, but the rest such as *t*-statistics, *F*-statistics, and their *p*-values will be the same because one is just a linearly rescaled version of the other.

An exception is when you have missing. For instance in a six item score, if 20% of the respondents missed a question then their scores will be the sum divided by 5; yet the remaining 80% with complete data would have their sum divided by 6. In those cases, the results from the sum and the mean can be completely different. And in those cases, perhaps mean is a closer approximation of the person's responses. Yet, be mindful that some respondents who answered only one out of, say, 30 items will then have that one score as the mean score. The analyst needs to make rules on exclusion due to overwhelming missing before computing the mean.

I am not entirely sure why SPSS is specifically mentioned here. But since it is, please also realize that in SPSS if you use `sum` and `mean` commands in the COMPUTE process, the answer will adjust for missing values. But if you use a chain of addition to compute the sum followed by dividing the number of items to get the mean, the result will be a system missing if any of your variables involved has a missing.

Comment: I would say $\bar{X}$ is easier for people to understand when you estimate the underlying parameter $\mu$. Although both $\sum X_i$ and $\bar{X}$ are  sufficient statistics for normal distributions. It is difficult to know what $\sum X_i$ is standing for.